# Rank ordering and/or classification problem

Tags: classification, ranking

I have about 10 variables about products. I need to rank order the products by quality. Now, the quality is very subjective thing, so I got all 300 products ranked by domain experts.

Now I have 10 variables, and ranking assigned by an expert. About 1% of products should be excelent, about 10% should be very good, 30% should be good, 30% should be average and the rest is below average.

What sort of modeling technique would you use to make sue of this data and create system which will automatically be able to classify product into those categories and mimic "expert judgement".

Comment: Could you please tell more about the dependent variable? How did the experts express their rankings? Did each expert rate all the products? If not how was it decided which product would be assessed by which expert?

Comment: 4 experts sat down around the table, discussed each products and rank ordered each product (in excel). Then they took first 1% of products and said "these products are excelent", then they took following 10% and said "these products are very good"... etc

Answer (score 3):

The dependent variable is ordinal (excellent > very good > good > average > below average). You could try ordinal logistic regression, with some variable selection method. After choosing the model you could tweak the thresholds to influence proportions falling into various categories.

Comment: How can I measure how good the model is? Don't have much experience using ordinal logistic regression?

Comment: I know I can use ROC, Gini or Accuracy Ratio for binary logistic regression, what are the model performance metrics for ordinal logistic regression model?

Answer (score 0):

An other approach would be taking the 1..300 ranks assigned to the products by the experts (temporarily neglecting the excellent/very good/... categorisation). You could try [ACE](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/acepack/acepack.pdf) (linear model with transformations of dependent variable and predictors), you may find that simple transformations of the predictors are satisfactory. Then you can set thresholds for the classification.

Comment: what sort of transformations are on your mind. Can you give some examples?