# What is the best way to convert learning to rank to pairwise preference learning?

Tags: machine-learning, ranking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rank ordering and/or classification problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9003/rank-ordering-and-or-classification-problem)

Suppose I have ordered objects for some queries.
Q1: o1,o2,o3,o4,o5

And I have learning to rank classifier which can be trained on data best from the list i,e,
o1 is better then o2,o3,o4,o5.
o2 is better then o3,o4,o5.

What is the best way to convert 1st problem to 2nd?

The are several different,

1. o1 vs rest
2. consequent pairs (o1,o2), (o2,o3), (o4, o5)
3. all pairs (o1,o2), (o1,o3), (o1, o5), (o2, o3) .... a lot of training data
4. one vs all below, (o1, o2-o5), (o2, o3-o5) ...

Which one is the best ?

Comment: So in summary, given an ordered list, you want to learn the [total ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) which has been used to sort the list. Is this correct ?

Comment: Do you have additional infos (descriptive features) or just the id of the objects ? How does your problem compare to this one: [Rank ordering and/or classification problem](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9003/rank-ordering-and-or-classification-problem)